# How to Save pytorch tensor in append mode

Tags: python, pytorch

How to save several tensor appending using `torch.save()`?

For example

```
for i in range(20):
       ......
    loss = criterion(scores, labels) 
    torch.save(loss,'loss.pt')
```

How to save these all 20 losses?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not possible to directly append to the file, at least, I could not find documentation for this. In your example, however, a better approach is to append to a list, and save at the end.

```
import torch

losses = []
for i in range(20):
    #   ......
    loss = criterion(scores, labels) 
    losses.append(loss.item())


torch.save(losses, 'loss.pt')
```